# What distinguishes the "nomenclature" from "definition"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) and [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) be regareded as synonyms?

Right now (February 16th, 2021), there are only 2 records tagged as [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature), and only 4 with tag [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition). This is not many, I agree, but browsing some questions made me believe, that at least the tag [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) might be useful (and I would volunteer to add that tag to more questions).

I also like the word "nomenclature" and I would like to keep it as a tag, but that's just my subjective view, so that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags are complementary. I didn't realize their usage was so low! [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) is for questions seeking for the correct terminology for a concept or for questions regarding the origin or usage of terminology. [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) is for questions seeking the meaning of a term or principle.

In the case of a question seeking the meaning of a term, you could argue [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) and [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) could both be applied, because the origin and usage of the term and its definition are relevant.

A question like "When did '**dwarf planet**' first come into use?" on the other hand would be [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) but not [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition).

A question like "What is the definition of Newton's law of gravitation?" might use [definition](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) but not [nomenclature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature), since it's not really interested in terminology but in the definition of a principle.